# Pandas mean of one column, by value of other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to output a dataframe showing the mean rating (based on 'AverageRating') of each of the listed genres.

Here's a mutilated version of the table as an example:

```
MovieID Movie_title     Action  Adventure   Animation   AverageRating               
1   Toy Story (1995)    0   0   1   3.878319
2   GoldenEye (1995)    1   1   0   3.206107
3   Four Rooms (1995)   0   0   0   3.033333
4   Get Shorty (1995)   1   0   0   3.550239
5   Copycat (1995)      0   0   0   3.302326
6   Shanghai Triad      0   0   0   3.576923
7   Twelve Monke(1995)  0   0   0   3.798469
8   Babe (1995)         0   0   0   3.995434
9   Dead Man W (1995)   0   0   0   3.896321
10  Richard III (1995)  0   0   0   3.831461
11  Seven (1995)        0   0   0   3.847458
12  Usual Suspec (1995) 0   0   0   4.385768
13  Mighty Aphro (1995) 0   0   0   3.418478
14  Postino, Il (1994)  0   0   0   3.967213
15  Mr. Holland's(1995) 0   0   0   3.778157
16  French Twist (1995) 0   0   0   3.205128
17  From Dusk Till      1   0   0   3.119565
18  White Balloon       0   0   0   2.800000
19  Antonia's Line      0   0   0   3.956522
20  Angels and Insects  0   0   0   3.416667
21  Muppet Treasure     1   1   0   2.761905
22  Braveheart (1995)   1   0   0   4.151515
23  Taxi Driver (1976)  0   0   0   4.120879
24  Rumble in the       1   1   0   3.448276
25  Birdcage            0   0   0   3.443686
```

So, I need to take the movies where Action = 1 etc, calculate the mean of AverageRating for those films and then create a dataframe, such as:

```
            AverageRating
Action      2.97
Adventure   3.14
Animation   3.30
```

Using pd.groupby, it's simple to do one column:

```
df.groupby(['Action'])['AverageRating'].mean()
```

```
Action
0    3.095288
1    2.966332
Name: AverageRating, dtype: float64
```

...but I'm struggling to work out how to do several columns at once in the way that is needed. I know there has to be a simple way to do it that I'm missing. Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can multiply the category with `AverageRating` and then average on mask:

```
cats = df.iloc[:, 2:-1]
s = cats.mul(df.AverageRating, axis='rows')
s.mask(s.eq(0)).mean()
# per comment, this is a better option
# s.mask(cats.eq(0)).mean()
```

Output:

```
Action       3.372934
Adventure    3.138763
Animation    3.878319
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much :)